# Get table row id on button click of modal box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing difficulty in small task because I am new to jQuery. I have a table where each table row has a icon, on click of that icon, a modal box opens containing some words. When I close this modal box, I want to gather table row which against that modal box appear.

For example:

```
table
  row1 +
  row2 +
  row3 +
```

On click of row2 + button, it open modal box, on closing of that modal box , I want that row against that modal box opened that will be 2 in that case.

I have written the code shown below.

Modal Box:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Choose words. You can add words, delete words </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" /> -->
      <div class="modal-body-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id = "modelformbuttonclick" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Table rows:

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>
<tr id="2">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>                   
<tr id="3">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>  
</table>
```

On click of modal box it get populated by dynamic value using jQuery.

```
$('tr #modelbox').click(function() {
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var tbid = $row.attr('id'); // table row ID
   var fieldOption = []
   $row.find('#words option').each(function() { fieldOption.push($(this).val()); });
   console.log(fieldOption);

    $('.modal-body-inner').html('');
    for(var i = 0, size = fieldOption.length; i < size ; i++){
          var item = fieldOption[i];
          $('.modal-body-inner').append("<span class=" + "span1" + " id = "+ tbid +"> "+ item + "</span>");
    }
});
```

And On click of Close button I want to get row, I am getting row like this but it is not working,

```
$('#modelformbuttonclick').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').data('id'));
    console.log($(event.target).closest('tr').data('id'));
});
```

So Hope you understand my question any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable outside the scope of your click event:

```
var tbid;

$('tr #modelbox').click(function() {
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   tbid = $row.attr('id'); // table row ID
   // .......
});

$('#modelformbuttonclick').click(function() {
    console.log("My clicked row was: " + tbid);
});
```

Comment: is there any other way too ?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the logical way I could think of in JQuery. And don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Just one small question if you help, how do I select table row on that tbid. Thanx

Comment: What do you mean by `selecting` the `tr` table row in question? if you need the object corresponding to that `tr`, you could simply reference it by `$('#' + tbid)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'data' attribute of modal to store the current `tbid`.

```js
$('tr #modelbox').click(function() {
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var tbid = $row.attr('id'); // table row ID
   var fieldOption = []
   
   // Save to modal Data
   $('#myModal').data('current', tbid);
   
   $row.find('#words option').each(function() { fieldOption.push($(this).val()); });
   // console.log(fieldOption);

    $('.modal-body-inner').html('');
    for(var i = 0, size = fieldOption.length; i < size ; i++){
          var item = fieldOption[i];
          $('.modal-body-inner').append("<span class=" + "span1" + " id = "+ tbid +"> "+ item + "</span>");
    }
});

$('#modelformbuttonclick').click(function() {
    // Read from modal Data
    console.log( $('#myModal').data('current') );
    // console.log($(this).closest('tr').data('id'));
    // console.log($(event.target).closest('tr').data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"/>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Choose words. You can add words, delete words </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" /> -->
      <div class="modal-body-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id = "modelformbuttonclick" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<table>
<tr id="1">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>
<tr id="2">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>                   
<tr id="3">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td> 
</td>  
</table>
```

Comment: Just one small question if you help, how do I select table row on that tbid. Thanx

Comment: `$('#' + tbid)`