# How to prevent modal to show up when users highlight text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a table where every row can toggle a dynamic modal form to modify the content of the `database` bound to the row. The code is looking like this :

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal"></tr>
```

The modal shows up correctly when we click on the row. But the modal shows up when we try to highlight some content of the row too.

How can make the modal shows up only when we click the row and not when we highlight the row ? I can use `Javascript` and `jQuery` as well.

**EDIT :**

Here is a snippet of my code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<table>
<thead>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td>Morris</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nt7hzkmw/1/

You can click on each row, it will displays the modal. But when you try to highlight some text, for example "smith" it will displays the modal form too

Comment: Use jquery/javascript on showing modal. It will just show when you have click the row. Here is the example of your problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070362/get-table-row-id-on-button-click-of-modal-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get table row id on button click of modal box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070362/get-table-row-id-on-button-click-of-modal-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Please can your share your complete code?

Comment: I edited my post to add a code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var tableid;

$('tr #myModal').click(function() {
   var $rows = $(this).closest('tr');
   tableid = $rows.attr('id'); // table row ID
   // .......
});
```

**HTML
Table**

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="fa fa-plus"></span></td> 
</td>
<tr id="2">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="fa fa-plus"></span></td> 
</td>                   
<tr id="3">
  <td><td>
  <td><span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="fa fa-plus"></span></td> 
</td>  
</table>
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Choose words. You can add words, delete words </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- <input type="text" value="Apple,banana,mango" data-role="tagsinput" /> -->
      <div class="modal-body-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id = "modelbtn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<table border=1>
    <tr onClick="toggleInfo()" >
        <td>
            just a dummy text
        </td>
        <td >
          td text goes here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Your popup model**

```
<div style="display:none" id="model">
    this is your model....
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
function toggleInfo() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selection);
    if(selection.type != "Range") {
    //  $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
        $("#model").toggle();
    }
}
```

I have not covered cosmetics stuff.
Hope this will helpful.

here is live example.
http://jsfiddle.net/yq810kvz/